# Why are these two function calls not equal to each other?

Tags: javascript, express, anonymous-function

Sorry if the title is so vague, I'm not sure how to explain it better.

Why does using an anonymous function call work in this case:

```
  Team
    .findAll()
    .then(function(teams) {
      res.send(teams);
    });
```

But passing `res.send` directly into the `.then()`, it doesn't work:

```
  Team
    .findAll()
    .then(res.send);
```

This results in this error:

```
Possibly unhandled TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of undefined
    at res.send (/opt/web/projects/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:83:27)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (/opt/web/projects/node_modules/sequelize/lib/promise.js:76:18)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
```

Aren't these two equal to each other? `res.send` only accepts one parameter, so it's not like it's passing some weird unknown argument into the function.

Comment: You already got your answer, but here is an example of passing a function  object member to a click handler, that demonstrates that you can just pass a property of a javascript object as a callback http://jsfiddle.net/bknjaf6k/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.then()` method expects you to pass it a function, because it's (eventually) going to **call** it. If you just pass a (non-function) value, that can't happen.

The point of calling `.then()` is to say, "when the operation has finished, please do *this*."

*edit* — ah OK, sorry. In this case, the problem is that when you pass `res.send` the `send` method will lose the context. That is, when the Promise mechanism makes a call to the `send` function, it won't know anything about the value of `res`.

You could do this:

```
  .then(res.send.bind(res))
```

By doing that, you ensure that when `send` is eventually called, it'll be called such that `this` will be a reference to your `res` object.

Comment: But `res.send` is a function, so shouldn't it just call it?

Comment: @RalphWiggum well is it a function that looks like the callback you passed in in the working code? Probably not, right?

Comment: Ah, thanks that makes sense! I'll accept your answer in a few moments.